# Bootstrap 3 - Vertically Align Label with Corresponding Div

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have reviewed all of the various answers here and on the web and I still can't get the labels to align properly vertically with their corresponding fields.

For example, I have something like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Referral Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Model.Referral_Number
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried various tricks, but the @Model.Referral_Number is vertically aligned to the top.

I have used the developer tools to inspect this and it seems to be occurring because the label control is **height 27** while the div is **height 20**, thus mis-aligning them.

What is the proper way to address this?  I realize I can force the height but is there a way to properly handle this using Bootstrap?

Comment: Providing a jsfiddle of your issue will help

Comment: its not a height issue.. it's a margin issue.. `control-label` class adds `bottom-margin:5px` so you need to add your own css style to the label or div beside it

Comment: That was the answer.   Adding margin-top:5px to the inner div now aligns them, thanks.   I just added a "margintop" CSS class and will put it next to the col-md-3 for all these fields.  Works great.